# Programming OO and classes

Tags: java, class, oop, object, constructor

I'm trying this ex but i cant find the problem; i can run it but it isn't as i would.
It should be a switch for light bulbs; i have my main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UsoLampadina {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        // Select the maximum number of clicks
        System.out.println("Selezionare il numero massimo di click:  ");    
        int click = scanner.nextInt();
        char s;
        int i= 0;


        Lampadina lamp = new Lampadina ( click , i);

        while (i >= 0){
            // Select the operation to be performed
            // V = Displays the status of the light bulb
            // C = Change the state of the bulb
            // Enter the selected operation:
            System.out.println("Selezionare l'operazione da eseguire: ");       
            System.out.println("[V] Visualizza lo stato della lampadina"); 
            System.out.println("[C] Cambia lo stato della lampadina"); 
            System.out.println("Immettere l'operazione selezionata: ");         
            s = scanner.next().charAt(0);


            switch (s) {
            case 'V': lamp.Stato(); break;
            case 'C': i = lamp.Click(); break;
            // Select a correct character
            default: System.out.println(" Selezionare un carattere corretto");  
            }
        } 
        // The light bulb broke!!!
        System.out.println("La lampadina si è rotta!!!"); 
        return;




    }

}
```

That open a menu where u can choose to see if the bulb is on or off (lamp.Stato()) or to change it state (turn off if it is on and viceversa, lamp.Click()). 
And my second class:

```
public class Lampadina {
    public int maxClick; 
    public int c = 0;
    public int i;


    public Lampadina ( int a, int b) {
        a = maxClick;       
        b = i;
    }

    public int Click() {
        while (click >= c ) {
            if ( i == 1 ) {
                c++;
                i = 0;
                return i;
            }
            else if (i == 0) {
                c++;
                i = 1;
                return i;
            }           
        }

        i = -1;
        return i;
    }


    public void Stato () {
        if (i == 0) {
            // The light bulb is off
            System.out.println("La lampadina è spenta");
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            // The light bulb is on
            System.out.println("La lampadina è accesa");
        }
        else if (i == -1) {
            // The light bulb is broken
            System.out.println("La lampadina è rotta");
        }
    }

}
```

Here i have the bulb's constructor method; and auxiliares (Click, Stato).
"Stato" works but i have problems with "Click"; it doesn't do what it should: 
the idea is that if the bulb is turned off (i == 0) it tunrs it on (return i = 1) and viceversa; c is a counter that, when it reachs the maxClicks (that u give as input in the main as a parametrer of the object "bulb") number; the bulb breaks.
when i run the programm it doesnt do the right number of cicle before the lamp breaks down

Comment: Is it a compile error because `click` is not defined in `Click`?

Comment: Btw I think you mixed up the left and the right side of the assignment in the constructor.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I've provided an English translation. I love Italian, but more programmers speak and write in English than Italian, so I think you will get better responses with English.

Answer (score 3):

you are setting parameter a and b to values instead set values to parameters

```
public Lampadina(int a, int b) {
    maxClick=a;       
    i=b;
}
```